# Reflect the member field of another object of class to behave as pointer in Java

Tags: java, pointers, data-structures, nodes

I have a class named `classA` which has member `remainingValues` which is type `ArrayList<Pair<Integer, classA>>`.

Class structure for classA:

```
classA {
    ...
    ArrayList<Pair<Integer,classA>> remainingValues;
}
```

Object `objA1` is created for the above `classA` and the value is initialized with remainingValues as,

```
<5, classA>
     |
     -> <4, null>
```

There is another class `classB` which initializes the object of `classA` as `objB1` and then copies all the value of `remainingValues` into it. However, it cannot be taken as reference for this new initialized object.

Now, I update the `remainingValues` in `objB1` and the values in remainingValues are as,

```
<5, classA>
     |
     -> <4, classA>
             |
             -> <2, classA>
                      |
                      -> <3, null>
```

So, when I update in the `objB1`, I should be able to update in the `remainingValues` in `objA1`.

I thought of an approach of updating objA1 just after the updating in objB1.

How can it be done effectively? I am facing this problem as I want to convert the program written in C++ which uses pointer to handle all these stuffs. In Java, I cannot use it as pointer but since it just uses reference, I am not been able to handle the updating of fields.

I have a partial code which tries to update the field of obj1A as,

```
public void updateRemainNodes(classA node) {
    if (!obj1A.remainingValues.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i=0; i<obj1A.remainingValues.size(); i++ ) {
            if (node.getName() == obj1A.remainingValues.get(i).getLeft()) {
                obj1A.remainingValues.get(i).setPair(node.getName(), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, I am able to update only if the value is null on the first level, but if it's on the another level, I am not able to update.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you write some code that shows your attempt of writing this, how it behaves, how you expect it to behave, etc? Write a [MCVE]

Comment: Updated the part of the code. I am only able to update if I find the node on the first level itself. If it's on the next level, it does not update.

Comment: can  you show the corresponding c++ code you use to do the work?

Comment: In C++, it has something like vector<int, classA*> remainingValues; so whatever it is done in remainingValues in classA, it is reflected all over the code as it is used as pointer.

Comment: i don't understand since you can update objB1  why can't you update objA
in the same way.